# Azure Continuous Integration for Web Apps Not Deploying to Deployment Slot

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment

I am using the AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml template to build and deploy to a staging Deployment Slot.  This is for an Azure Website.  The build runs and executes successfully.  However the code is not being deployed to the staging slot.  I have included the Web Deploy Publish Profile in the configuration.  I am not getting any errors and it said that it has completed.  What am I doing wrong?

As info, I've been following this guide:
[Azure Deployment Slots](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/)

[image: Config]

Comment: I am using the new build system in VSO and I am facing the same issue. The build completes successfully but the slot remains empty.

Comment: Never mind, looks like I just need to specify “staging” in the slot name field and the build task will create “foo-staging” automatically. If I specify “foo-staging” in the slot name field, then it will create a slot named “foo-foo-staging”.